# Delete multiple selected record from a multiselect listbox (Access)

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I need to delete multiple records selected from a listbox in Access. I have SQL and VBA to delete one selected record from a non-multiselect listbox, but I can't seem to adapt the code to delete multiple selected records from a multiselect listbox. Here's the code as it stands; it's attached to a button On_Click event and the listbox is called listboxname:

```
Private Sub DeleteSelected_Click()
    Dim lngID As Long
    Dim strSQL As String

    If IsNull(ListBoxName) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Me.ListBoxName

    lngID = ListBoxName.Value

    strSQL = "DELETE * FROM [tablename] WHERE [tablefieldname] =" & lngID

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

    ListBoxName.Requery

    End With
End Sub
```

I tried setting

```
lngID = ListBoxName.Value
```

to

```
lngID = ListBoxName.ItemsSelected(0)
```

or

```
lngID = ListBoxName.Columns(0)
```

to no avail. It seems like the SQL must be at fault, but I haven't a clue how to fix it. Any ideas?

EDIT: That's very cool :) Cheers Belial. Here is the updated code

```
    Private Sub DeleteSelected_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim vItem As Variant
    Dim strSet As Long

    If IsNull(ListBoxName) Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With Me.ListBoxName
      For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
                If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
                    strSet = strSet & "," & .ItemData(vItem)
                End If
            Next
        End With

    strSQL = "DELETE FROM Carers WHERE Carer_ID IN (" & strSet & ")"

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

    ListBoxName.Requery

    End Sub
```

Hope I'm doing this right

Answer (score 1):

Here is one SQL error in your query:

```
strSQL = "DELETE FROM [tablename] WHERE [tablefieldname] =" & lngID
```

There's no need for `*`.

Anyway, here is another way you can do:

Get select items into a String separated by `,` comma, then use `IN` operator to delete all at once.

```
Dim vItem as Variant
Dim strSet as String
//Loop through the ItemsSelected in the list box    
    With Me.ListBoxName
        For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
            If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
                strSet = strSet & "," & .ItemData(vItem) 
            End If
        Next
    End With
strSQL = "DELETE FROM [tablename] WHERE [tablefieldname] IN (" & strSet & ")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the * from the DELETE Statement.

```
strSQL = "DELETE FROM [tablename] WHERE [tablefieldname] =" & lngID
```

to iterate through the selected items use something like

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
      If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
         Msg = Msg & ListBox1.List(i) & vbNewLine
     End If
Next i
```

see

iteration: http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Forms/GettheselecteditemsinaListBox.htm

delete statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845201(v=office.14).aspx

does it work now?

**EDIT**

i think nothing happens because this is always true in my opinion (tried it).

```
If IsNull(ListBoxName) Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

try this

```
Dim strSQL As String
Dim vItem As Variant

With Me.ListBoxName
    For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
        If Not IsNull(vItem) And Not CStr(vItem) = vbNullString Then
            strSQL = "DELETE FROM Carers WHERE Carer_ID = " & CLng(vItem)
            CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
        End If
    Next
End With

ListBoxName.Requery
```

Comment: Thanks loads for the responses! :D never imagined getting feedback so quick. Sorry Belial09, your code gets hung up on the .List part of ListBox1.List [line 3]; Access 2013 doesn't seem to recognise it. bonCodigo, while that code looks great and doesn't throw up any errors, it also doesn't seem to do anything. I inserted it into the existing code, ran the form and clicked the relevant button; literally nothing happened. I have no idea why :( I'll keep mucking about with the layout of it anyway, it seems like something's not being called rather than something's breaking

Comment: can you post (edit) an updated version of your code, i will have a look at it :)

Comment: thanks for trying but it still wont work. I removed the If IsNull statement from the code and swapped in the code you suggested to no avail. I think I'm just gonna leave it for now, not really getting anywhere, but I'll leave the thread open just in case. Cheers for all your help :)