# MS Access - Multi Select Listbox to delete records from table

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, multi-select

I am using Access 2010 on Windows 8.  I was looking for a way to use a multi select listbox to delete several records from a table at once.  I came accross this post on StackOverflow and it helped get me started:

[Delete multiple selected record from a multiselect listbox (Access)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15108356/delete-multiple-selected-record-from-a-multiselect-listbox-access)

I adjusted the code in the solution to work with my tables and objects but for some reason it only works when one record is selected.  If I select 2 or more records then nothing happens.  Can anyone take a look and help help me see where I might have made a mistake?

```
Private Sub cmdRemoveProducts_Click()

    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim vItem       As Variant
    Dim strSet      As Long


    'If IsNull(lstOperationProducts) Then
        'Exit Sub
    'End If

    With Me.lstOperationProducts
        For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
            If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
                strSet = strSet & "," & .ItemData(vItem)
            End If
        Next
    End With

    strSQL = "DELETE FROM tblOperationProductMM WHERE OpProdID IN (" & strSet & ")"

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL

    lstProducts.Requery
    lstOperationProducts.Requery


End Sub
```

EDIT:

Thanks for all your help, I ended up getting it to work, I think that the main problem was that strSet was declared as long instead of interger.  It ended up working ok without surrounding the comma in the with statement with single quotes.

This the final product:

```
Private Sub cmdRemoveProducts_Click()

    Dim strSQL      As String
    Dim vItem       As Variant
    Dim strSet      As String
    Dim i           As Long


    'If IsNull(lstOperationProducts) Then
        'Exit Sub
    'End If

    strSet = ""

    With Me.lstOperationProducts
        For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
            If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
                strSet = strSet & "," & .ItemData(vItem)
            End If
        Next
    End With

    ' Remove the first comma
    strSet = Mid(Trim(strSet), 2, Len(strSet) - 1)

    strSQL = "DELETE FROM tblOperationProductMM WHERE OpProdID IN (" & strSet & ")"

    CurrentDb.Execute strSQL



        For i = 0 To lstProducts.ListCount - 1
        lstProducts.Selected(i) = False
    Next

        For i = 0 To lstOperationProducts.ListCount - 1
        lstOperationProducts.Selected(i) = False
    Next

    lstProducts.Requery
    lstOperationProducts.Requery
```

Comment: If you select multiple items what is the final sql that's created? as it is written now it looks like you leave a leading comma in `strSet`

Comment: use the debugger to step through your code and see what its doing. check the variable values on each level, check what methods it does ro does not drop in to.

Comment: aaah, i see.  

Aaah, I see.  The query is trying to concatenate both record IDs into a single record ID and then delete that record (which doesn't exist obviously).

i'm not sure how I can tell it to keep the record IDs seperate and delete both records though.  I'll keep researching and post back if I find something.  if anyone has suggestions they are appreciated as well :)

Thanks!

Comment: Brad, the SQL that it's creating is: 

"DELETE FROM "tblOperationProductsMM" WHERE OpProdID IN (131132)"

131 is the first record ID
132 is the second Record ID

Comment: The query I was hoping it was creating was: 

"DELETE FROM "tblOperationProductsMM" WHERE OpProdID IN (131,132)"

Comment: @brharrii - You can not dim strSet as Long.  Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace this:

```
With Me.lstOperationProducts
    For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
        If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
            strSet = strSet & "," & .ItemData(vItem)
        End If
    Next
End With
```

with:

```
strSet = ""

With Me.lstOperationProducts
    For Each vItem In .ItemsSelected
        If Not IsNull(vItem) Then
            strSet = strSet & "," & .ItemData(vItem)
        End If
    Next
End With

' Remove the first comma
strSet = Mid(Trim(strSet), 2, Len(strSet) - 1)
```

Also, remember that if the item in question is Text, you will need to surround it with single quotes.  So this line:

```
            strSet = strSet & "," & .ItemData(vItem)
```

Would be:

```
            strSet = strSet & "','" & .ItemData(vItem)
```

And the last line would need to be changed to:

```
strSet = Mid(Trim(strSet), 3, Len(strSet) - 2) & "'"
```

**EDIT:** I just saw you're also Diming the variable **strSet** as LONG.  You can't do that, because [LONG is an Integer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y595sc15.aspx).  You have to Dim it as a String.

Comment: `strSet as LONG` explains why his query statement included `WHERE OpProdID IN (131132)` That happened because `CLng(131 & "," & 132)` returns 131132.